# “Cookies were cooked deliciously.”

Tags: passive-voice

Does “cookies were cooked deliciously by someone” and “someone cooked cookies deliciously” mean the same and grammatically okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question: yes, both sentences would mean the same thing.

Both sentences are grammatical, however neither sentence is natural for several reasons, and they probably don't mean what you want to say.

A complete, idiomatic sentence would look like this:

> someone baked some delicious cookies

Here is an explanation of the changes.

---

When we talk about preparing food, we generally only use the verb **cook** about a complete meal, for example:

> I cooked dinner for eight people last night

When we talk about preparing just one item we use the verb that describes the specific way of preparing it:

> I baked some bread
> I boiled some eggs
> I roasted a joint - *(of meat)*

For things that don't require heat, we use the word **make**.

> I made some lemonade
> I made some salad

**make** can also be used for things that require cooking, but you have to be careful:

> I made some burgers

would mean that you prepared the patties, but did not cook the,

---

> someone cooked cookies deliciously

In this sentence, the adverb **deliciously** modifies the verb **cooked**, meaning that the activity of cooking is delicious. OK, you get the lick the spoons sometimes, but.... I don't think that **cook** or any other activity can be delicious.

You can only really use the adverb **deliciously** to modify an adjective, for example:

> The curry was deliciously spicy.

It's probably the cookies that you want to describe, rather than the activity, so you should use the adjective **delicious**.

---

When you want to emphasise the product, rather than the activity of producing it, you generally add a determiner, like **some**.

> I made lemonade yesterday- *ephasises your activity*
> I made **some** lemonade yesterday- *emphasises the product of your activity*

When you want to say that the product is delicious, you really need that determiner.

Comment: Then, “I baked delicious cookies” can replace “I made delicious cookies”?

Comment: Yes, you can.  Bake means "to cook inside an oven", which is how you make cookies. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bake https://sallysbakingaddiction.com/chewy-chocolate-chip-cookies/

Answer (score 1):

They're both grammatically acceptable, but rather than an adverb to modify *how* the cooking was done, it might be more sensible to use an adjective to describe the "delicious cookies."

It would also be reasonable to modify the verb with something more applicable, e.g., "lovingly," or "artistically."

Comment: But my teacher said “someone cooked cookies deliciously” means someone is delicious, not cookies are delicious.

Comment: It actually means the action of cooking is delicious, not the cook or the resulting cookies.

Comment: @Peter Does “I played soccer interestedly” also mean the action is interested?

Comment: No, it describes the way I played soccer, and it means that the way I played soccer was the result of my interest.

Comment: 'Someone cooked cookies in a delicious way', which is grammatical but not meaningful.  Also, it would sound better  to say 'baked cookies'.